# g++ L"string~" + operator like Visual C++

Tags: c++, string, visual-c++, g++, operator-overloading

in Visual C++,

```
CString a = L"Hello " + L"World!";
```

or

```
CString a = L"" + 123;
```

can be done, right?

L"~" is wchar* type, but how it can be done?

Is it valid only for Visual C++? I mean, is it supported at Visual C++'s complier level? And g++ cannot do?

Or can I overload primitive(global) operator something like

```
wchar_t* operator+(wchar_t* L, wchar_t* R){...}
```

Comment: The first should not compile per C++ rules of adding two pointers, and the second is undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

Your first example (`L"Hello " + L"World!"`) can't be done as-is. It would require addition of string literals (or pointers, to which they can convert), which simply isn't allowed.

One alternative, would be to leave the `+` out, and depend upon string concatenation:

```
CString a = L"Hello" L"World!";
```

[At compile time, if you have two string literals, with nothing between them, the compiler will concatenate the two into a single string literal. This only works with *literals* though--something like a string object + a literal requires an operator.]

Another possibility (assuming you're using a new enough version of VC++) would be to define a user-defined literal operator, to create literals of type `CString`, in which case you'd be using the existing `operator+` for CStrings.

```
CString operator""_cs(TCHAR const *in) { return CString(in); }

// ...

CString a = L"hello"_cs + L"World!"_cs;
```

As for the second example (`a = L"" + 123;`) this *syntax* is already allowed--adding a pointer and an integer yields a pointer incremented by that integer, so (for example) `L"012345" + 2` will give a pointer to the `2` in the `L"012345"`.

Therefore, you can use that existing capability, but you can't use an operator overload to change what it does.

If your intent was to convert the `123` to a string, you could (for example) use `std::to_string(123)` (but this produces a result of type `std::string`, not `CString`).

The basic rule with operator overloads in general is that at least one operand must be of a user-defined type (or a reference to a user-defined type). If both operands are built-in types, it's simply not allowed.

All of the preceding is portable provided the compiler is new enough (but user defined literals were added in C++11, so older compilers don't include them). VC++ includes a class named `CString` as part of its MFC library. gcc doesn't include that, but a similar class could be written for it if desired.

Comment: It's a little bit unfortunate that there's no actual release of VS that supports UDLs yet, but at least the 2015 preview does.